# sqlite3 row number

Tags: sql, sqlite, window-functions, better-sqlite3

I have the following data

| IDX | DATA |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | a |
| 3 | a |
| 4 | b |
| 5 | b |
| 6 | b |
| 7 | b |
| 8 | b |
| 9 | c |
| 10 | c |

How can I, using Sqlite3, get the row count as such

| IDX | DATA | COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 1 / 3 |
| 2 | a | 2 / 3 |
| 3 | a | 3 / 3 |
| 4 | b | 1 / 5 |
| 5 | b | 2 / 5 |
| 6 | b | 3 / 5 |
| 7 | b | 4 / 5 |
| 8 | b | 5 / 5 |
| 9 | c | 1 / 2 |
| 10 | c | 2 / 2 |

Thanks for you help

Comment: Just to make the results a little more useful would it be possible to add the total number of rows per group?
i.e.
1 / 3
2 / 3
3 / 3
1 / 5
2 / 5
3 / 5
4 / 5
5 / 5
1 / 2
2 / 2

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! It is better to think of this community like you do for Wikipedia. Users come here with a specific question in mind, looking for a specific answer. Therefore, we require a description of the problem _and_ your own attempt at solving the problem. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

Use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
SELECT
    IDX,
    DATA,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DATA ORDER BY IDX) COUNT
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    IDX;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

You need ROW_NUMBER() window function:

```
SELECT *, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DATA ORDER BY IDX) AS COUNT
FROM tablename
```